# c# forms: where do i place my random number generator?

Tags: c#, forms, random

I was trying to use a random number generator in a windows forms app, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to put it. I'm being told "place it in the form constructor" but I don't think we're talking the same language. Here's the code im trying to find a home for:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int guessMe = rnd.Next(0,100);
```

But whenever I try to place it outside of the click even method, it says:

> A field initializer cannot reference
>   the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'LAB6B.Form1.r'

So i'm assuming that means what it sounds like; it has to be inside of a static method. But the form constructor doesn't seem to have any static methods either. Can someone toss me a bone?

---

Here is the code from the the Form1.cs. Im reading some other tutorial online right now that is saying to do the random number generator in the Form1_Load event, but I'm getting a context/scope error from the button click event.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace LAB6B
    {

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();            

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int guessMe = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }

            private void btnEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                int totGuesses = 0, myGuess;

                if (txtGuess.Text != "")
                {
                    myGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);
                    totGuesses++;
                    if (myGuess < guessMe)
                    {
                        btnEvaluate.Visible = false;
                        lblResult.Text = "Too Low!!";
                        lblResult.Visible = true;
                        BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've been given that advice, someone is probably suggesting that you declare an instance variable, but initialize it in your constructor. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Random rnd;

    public Foo()
    {
        rnd = new Random();
        // Other construction code
    }
}
```

Then you can use `rnd` anywhere in your class.

This is actually mostly equivalent to:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public Foo()
    {
        // Other construction code
    }
}
```

... which I mostly prefer, as it shows that the initialization of `rnd` has nothing to do with any constructor parameters.

As it seems that part of your difficulty is with the `guessMe` variable, here's a more complete version:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    private int guessMe;

    public Foo()
    {
        guessMe = rng.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```

This is assuming you need `guessMe` to be an instance variable so you can refer to it throughout the class. On the other hand, perhaps you don't need the `Random` variable to be an instance variable - if you're only generating one random number, it would be better as:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int guessMe;

    public Foo()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        guessMe = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```

However, personally I wouldn't use either of these approaches. I would use a technique which creates a single instance of `Random` per thread, to avoid both the perils of `Random` being non-thread-safe, and the perils of creating two instances of `Random` very close to each other in time, and ending up with the same seeds.

I've written about this reasonably extensively in an [article on my site](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx), including this class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class RandomProvider
{    
    private static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    private static ThreadLocal<Random> randomWrapper =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() =>
            new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed))
        );

    public static Random GetThreadRandom()
    {
        return randomWrapper.Value;
    }
}
```

You can either use `RandomProvider` directly (calling `GetThreadRandom` every time you need to generate a random number) or you can pass `RandomProvider.GetThreadRandom` into your class as a constructor argument for a parameter of type `Func<Random>` - i.e. inject a dependency of "I want to be able to get an instance of `Random` at any time".

Comment: I really appreciate the detail. It still isn't really working for me but I think you're a bit above my skill and the scope of what I'm trying to accomplish lol. Its a class assignment to create a number guessing game. So im using the forms and code generated by C#.net, basic file set up; Form1.cs, Form1.Designer.cs, and Program.cs  I'm not sure where to make the random number generator work. Is it a complication with partial classes? I'm having scope issues.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: No, it shouldn't be anything to do with being partial - but it's hard to say what's wrong when you haven't provided much context. If you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we could explain things more clearly. (Although I'm unlikely to be posting again tonight.)

Comment: ok i figured it out based on what you told me.public partial class Form1 : Form { public static readonly Random rnd = new Random(); int guessMe = rnd.Next(0,100); this finally got rid of the error stating that it couldnt be accessed outside of a static method. Everything looks good and the variable is now global :) thanks!

Comment: @Sinaeshetic: No, that's not a good way to do it. Static variables holding instances of Random are a bad idea. Make `rnd` an instance variable, but put the `guessMe` initialization in a method or the constructor. I've edited my answer with some examples.

Comment: From http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx, it appears that @JonSkeet himself has moved away from the idea of using by-thread `Random`s in multithreaded contexts, advocating instead the usage of a single `Random` instance with a lock to be acquired by callers.